# Laravel how to convert from created_at (timestamp) to date with query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I tried to convert created_date to date with query builder, but I have no luck.
I know I can convert it in view with blade, but I need this in the query because I want to use it for dataTables function.
I tried mysql code manually, it's work normally .

here my code:

```
$convert = \DB::raw("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((created_at), '%e %c %Y') AS tanggal");
$bonus = bonus_transaction::select('id', "$convert", 'transaction_type', 'amount_usd_out' , 'status_withdraw')
        ->where('transaction_type', 'Reinvest')->get();
```

I got error like this

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT((created_at), %e %c %Y)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id`, `SELECT DATE_FORMAT((created_at), %e %c %Y)` as `tanggal`, `transaction_type`, `amount_usd_out`, `status_withdraw` from `bonus_transaction_log` where `transaction_type` = Reinvest)"
```

Comment: in your query its created_at but in question title its says created_date.as per error i guess column field is wrong

Comment: @iCoders sorry typo. I fix the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `SELECT` as you are already uisng `select()` in laravel, change here

```
$convert = \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT('created_at', '%e %c %Y') as tanggal");
```

Comment: well, I didn't see that. But I still got error after remove Select SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE_FORMAT((created_at), %e %c %Y)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id`, `DATE_FORMAT((created_at), %e %c

Comment: still error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%e %c %Y')' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id`, `DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%e %c %Y')` as `tanggal`, `transaction_type`, `amount_usd_out`, `status_withdraw` from `bonus_transaction_log` where `transaction_type` = Reinvest)

Comment: @BillyOrigin : copy exact what I post. you have not `'` single qotes in your query

Comment: Also try without `"` double quote in select method as `$convert` instead `"$convert"`

Comment: Its working in my model `$convert = \DB::raw("Select DATE_FORMAT('created_at', '%e %c %Y') as tanggal");
        $response  = Model::select("id",$convert)->first();
            return dd($response);`

Answer (score 1):

can you try this one .Asi noticed you have added extra parenthesis to created_at

```
$convert = \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%e %c %Y') AS tanggal");
    $bonus = bonus_transaction::select('id', "$convert", 'transaction_type', 'amount_usd_out' , 'status_withdraw')
            ->where('transaction_type', 'Reinvest')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can finally fix my code, thanks everyone. Here the answer.

```
$convert = \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%e/%c/%Y') as tanggal");
$bonus = bonus_transaction::select('id', $convert, 'transaction_type', 'amount_usd_out' , 'status_withdraw')->where('transaction_type', 'Reinvest')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest use Model Eloquent for better solution
for dates just type in your model

```
protected $dates = ['created_at'];
```

Hope its Helpfull for you